# Javascript is giving invalid month when month is set to 5

Tags: javascript

I am getting invalid date when I set month as 5 in JavaScript date object.
I know that Month is zero based. so, month 5 means June.
But I am getting month as July.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Click the button to display the date after changing the month.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setYear(2017);
        d.setMonth(5);
        d.setDate(30);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = d.getMonth();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>

Output:

6

Sun Jul 30 2017 15:11:20 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)



But, Ideally the output should be:
5
Sat Jun 30 2017 15:11:20 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

Comment: getMonth and setMonth start from 0 and end at 11

Comment: maybe 5 month doesn't have 30 day so it skips one month forward

Comment: There is weirdness because today is the `31st` and some months don't have a `31st`. You can't set the y/m/d one by one unless you start with a known date.

Comment: @Luke All months have 30 days, except February.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But some also have 31.

Comment: @AthMav "I know that Month is zero based"

Comment: Set the day before the month.

Comment: I believe this question will be reasked again in exactly one year ... ;)

Comment: Many duplicates, but none that is really good (afaict): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+setMonth+date

Comment: Take care when spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what happens:

```
var d = new Date();
//d is today : which is 31st of May (day of your test)

d.setMonth(5)
//5 is June (setMonth starts at 0)
//As 31st of June doesn't exist, it is set as 1st of July.

d.setDate(30)
//d is now 30th of July
```

You'd better use the full [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
new Date(year, month, date);
```

Answer (score 4):

Today is *May 31st 2017*.

When you set the month to `5` which is `June`, the day is still `31` but there is no `June 31`. At this point behavior is undefined or at least unclear; anything could happen really.

To avoid it, create the date like this:

```
var date = new Date(2017, 5, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because setMonth will also set the day, but we are on 31 and June only contains 30 days, so the date will change to 1 July. Then on July 30th thanks to the setDay. Try to set the day before, normally it should work.

Comment: @dav: But after they change the month, at which point the date was already "corrected".

Comment: It's said AFTER setting the month. so, when the month is set, the code will take the current day which is 31

Comment: Alix is correct, he just doesn't explain it perfectly.